# Python Enum: How to get enum values with multiple attributes

Tags: python, enums

I have defined two enums with attributes. When I want to access an enum element by specifying its attribute it works for enum `A` (one attribute) but not for enum `B` (two attributes):

```
from enum import Enum

class A(Enum):
    ValOne = ('One')
    ValTwo = ('Two')

    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

class B(Enum):
    ValOne = ('Val', 'One')
    ValTwo = ('Val', 'Two')

    def __init__(self, val, num):
        self.val = val
        self.num = num

print(A('One'))
print(B('Val', 'One'))
```

I get the following output:

```
A.ValOne
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(B('Val', 'One'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 341, in __call__
    return cls._create_(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 444, in _create_
    _, first_enum = cls._get_mixins_(cls, bases)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 576, in _get_mixins_
    raise TypeError("Cannot extend enumerations")
TypeError: Cannot extend enumerations
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is `B(('Val', 'One'))`, passing the value of the enum directly (thus in this case a tuple), or simply naming the enum variant by name: `B.ValOne`.

I must admit this is confusing, with `__init__` automagically destructuring the tuple into two arguments. The error isn't helpful either.

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE**

In Python 3.12 the effective signature for by-value look-up will be:

```
B(*values)
```

So

```
B('Val', 'One')
```

will work as expected and return

```
<B.ValOne: ('Val', 'One')>
```

while

```
B(('Val', 'One'))
```

will continue to work correctly.

---

The biggest thing you missing is that `('One')` is not a `tuple` -- you need a comma (`,`), which would look like `('One', )`.

So `A` is made of single, non-tuple, values `'One'` and `'Two'`.

`B`, however, is made of tuples, *but*

```
 B('Val', 'One')
```

is not passing a `tuple` to `B`, it is passing two arguments: `'Val'` and `'One'`.  As @orlp mentioned, passing a tuple using function syntax looks like:

```
B(('Val', 'One'))
```

Finally, in the definitions of `A`'s and `B`'s members, you do not need the parentheses:

```
class A(Enum):
    ValOne = 'One'
    ValTwo = 'Two'

    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num


class B(Enum):
    ValOne = 'Val', 'One'
    ValTwo = 'Val', 'Two'

    def __init__(self, val, num):
        self.val = val
        self.num = num
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.